# null value in JSON is not interpreted by python for openstack API

Tags: python, json, openstack, openstack-nova

I am using OpenStack's REST API for programmatic implementation of start or stop server.

The link for API reference is http://api.openstack.org/api-ref.html#ext-os-server-start-stop
This requires a dictionary in python as follows:

```
dict = {
     os-start:null
    }
```

Then I am doing a json.dumps(dict) and making a post request to the openstack's public URL for nova module.

When I run this program ,error of unknown global name "null". Hence, its not working.

I want to know for this request of starting the server on OpenStack to work , what should I use as the value of field "os-start" in request JSON.

Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's `None` singleton is translated to a JSON `null`, and vice versa. Use that instead:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'os-start': None})
'{"os-start": null}'
>>> json.loads('{"os-start": null}')
{u'os-start': None}
```

Comment: Ya sure that doesn't give any Error like previously. But the openstack server is responding with Error code 400 "BadRequest" saying that "There is no such action: None". The data after json.dumps is '{"os-start":null}'. So, why this is not working ?

Comment: @AkshayPatil: That I don't know. By the looks of it, the value of the JSON object is ignored anyway (only the key appears to carry meaning).

Comment: The Content-Type should be specified rightly, I found that now. "Content-Type:application/json" while making the request. Now this works.

Answer (score 1):

May be little off-topic, but as you are using openstack REST API, I also recommend to take a look at [libcloud](http://libcloud.apache.org/) as well, it has openstack driver.

Libcloud not only provides a unified interface to the cloud, but also the abstract the access layer to openstack REST API